# Documenting library/mixin/behaviors elements in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I had a Polymer 0.5 element that I mainly used as a library which I injected into other elements using mixins.  I formatted it as followed and all of the JSDoc notation showed up in `index.html`:

```
<polymer-element name="easy-search-lib" attributes="">

  <template>

    <content></content>

  </template>

  <script>

    var EasySearch = {

      /**
       * Returns whether the given domain matches search.
       *
       * @method matches
       * @param {String} query String being searched for.
       * @param {String} text Text being searched within.
       * @return {Boolean} Returns if there is a match.
       */
      matches: function(query, text){
        query = this.getQuery(query);
        return query.test(text);
      }

      //...

    };

    Polymer(Polymer.mixin({

      /**
       * Convenience function for testing, binds EasySearch to Polymer element.
       *
       * @attribute EasySearch
       * @type object
       */
      EasySearch: EasySearch

    }, EasySearch));

  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Polymer 1.0 replaced mixins with [behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) and gives the following example:

```
<script>
    HighlightBehavior = {

      properties: {
        isHighlighted: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false,
          notify: true,
          observer: '_highlightChanged'
        }
      },

      listeners: {
        click: '_toggleHighlight'
      },

      created: function() {
        console.log('Highlighting for ', this, + 'enabled!');
      },

      _toggleHighlight: function() {
        this.isHighlighted = !this.isHighlighted;
      },

      _highlightChanged: function(value) {
        this.toggleClass('highlighted', value);
      }

    };
</script>
```

Note that there is no `<dom-module id="highlight-behavior">` nor `Polymer({...})`
element declaration.

I followed this example exactly, but nothing showed up when I visited index.html.  So I tried emulating what I had done for 0.5:

```
<script>

  var EasySearchLib = {

    EasySearch : {

      /**
       * Returns whether the given domain matches search.
       *
       * @method matches
       * @param {String} query String being searched for.
       * @param {String} text Text being searched within.
       * @return {Boolean} Returns if there is a match.
       */
      matches: function(query, text){
        query = this.getQuery(query);
        return query.test(text);
      }

      //...
     }
  };

  Polymer({

    is: 'easy-search-lib',

    properties: {

      /**
       * `fancy` indicates that the element should don a monocle and tophat,
       * while checking its pocket watch.
       */
      EasySearchLib: EasySearchLib
    }

  });

</script>
```

I also tried declaring variations of the attribute assignment (`EasySearch: EasySearchLib.EasySearch`) and throwing in a `behaviors: [EasySearchLib]` but nothing shows up in the documentation.

What's the best way of getting documentation for behaviors/libraries to show up when visiting index.html?

Answer (score 2):

Put this before your behavior object definition:

```
/** @polymerBehavior */
var MyBehavior = {};
```

If you are putting multiple behaviors in one object, you will probably want to use this:

```
var EasySearchLib = {

  /** @polymerBehavior EasySearchLib.EasySearch */
  EasySearch: {}
}
```

Alternatively, I am in a similar situation where I define my namespace object beforehand with:

```
var EasySearchLib = EasySearchLib || {};
```

At the head of the document, then define the behavior with:

```
/** @polymerBehavior */
EasySearchLib.EasySearch = {};
```

This lets the parser infer the name of the behavior pretty easily.  It also allows you to split the individual behaviors into separate files and attach them in any order.

Additional documentation: http://polymerelements.github.io/style-guide/#behaviors

Comment: This won't show any documentation for functions/objects further than a single step down – meaning that I either have to pollute every other element's namespace or lose out on documentation.  Where should I file a ticket?

Comment: I don't follow. You should be able to put `/** @polymerBehavior */` before each Behavior you define and it will be documented.

Comment: This [code](http://pastebin.com/N8PxcrwN) results in [this documentation](http://imgur.com/vOM2s39)....

Comment: That looks right to me.  Does the dropdown selector in the top-left not include `EasySearchLib.EasySearch`?

Comment: Maybe that form should be supported, but I found a different setup that does work, I will correct your answer.

Comment: I had to reject your edit as it was incorrect.  When you use the form as described in my answer, the documentation will infer the `EasySearchLib.EasySearch` name automatically.

Comment: Your code sample uses the form `var EasySearchLib = {EasySearch:{}}` which *does* require providing an explicit behavior name in the documentation comment, however.

Comment: Okay, so now it's working the way you documented it, but now I have to define the behavior as EasySearchLib.EasySearch which also removes the EasySearch prefix from the local namespace.  The reason I want to add the EasySearch component is because I want to avoid namespace conflicts.

Comment: In your component, use `behaviors: [EasySearchLib.EasySearch]`